# Mysql data retriving in perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

```
Connect with mysql and retrive data from the table.

  my $db ="JJusers";
  my $user ="root";
  my $password ="abcdef";
  my $host ="localhost";

  my $dbh =DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host",$user,$password);

  my $uDt = $dbh->prepare("select Username,Password from Users");
  my $rv = $uDt->execute;

  print "<script>alert($rv)</script>";
```

When I execute this code I am getting the result as `1`. In database the data stored as:

```
1, jj, pp(SNO, USERNAME,PASSWORD)
```

Why isn't it getting the right data?

Comment: Are you following the DBI documentation?  You can get it either from `perldoc DBI`, or online at http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the result of `execute`, not the actual database results. You want to do something like this...

```
while (my @data = $rv->fetchrow_array()) {
    my $username = $data[0];
    my $password = $data[1];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Global symbol "@data" requires explicit package name . how to fix this?

Comment: Use `my` before `@data`. It's because you are using `use strict` Answer updated.

Comment: How to redirect the and page when the button is clicked. how to work onclick in perl cgi script.

Comment: You should post that as a new question along with a code sample of what you tried.

Comment: print "User name:\t";

            print $q->textfield(
              -name => 'UserName',
              -value =>'JJ',
              -size  => 30,
              -maxlength =>50,
            );
 
        my $uName = $q->param('UserName');
        print "<script>alert($uName)</script>";

when i use this i dont get jj on the alert  its not reading the textfield value.
i want to the value of the text field

Answer (score 0):

->execute returns just query result(0, 1, 0E0), but not resultset.
As for me, best way is:

```
my $res = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('select Username,Password from Users', {Slice=>{}});
# now, you can iterate result.
# for example:
foreach my $row(@$res) {
    print $row->{Username};
}
```

If you need bind vaiables, you can use selectall_arrayref also:

```
my $res = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('select Username,Password from Users where id = ?',
    {Slice=>{}}, 1
);
```